# I don't know why I'm recieving this function error - Python

Tags: python

I am writing an inventory 'system' in python.

```
import time, math, items
from pygame.locals import *
while 1:
    def additem(item):
        if item in items:
            items.extend(item)
            print(item+' has been succefully added to your inventory.') 
        else:
            print("Invalid command.")
```

This is items.py

```
items = ['sword','cheese']
```

I recieve the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    additem(sword)
NameError: name 'additem' is not defined
```

Comment: Why is there a `while 1:` infinite loop at the top? Where is the code that throws the exception itself?

Comment: I put the infinite loop because I want it to run like a command line 
(for now). And I am calling the function in the shell.

Comment: Leave that to the pygame event loop instead. If you imported this module *as is* into the shell, the `import` statement would never complete *anyway*.

Comment: Also logic-wise: Do you maybe want to add the item if it is NOT yet in items + do you want to extend or append to the list?

Comment: Sorry I haven't said what I meant. The items array will be all the items that exist. The function should add to a different array which I haven't done. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list called `items` inside a module named `items`, when you call `additem` you are going to be checking `if item in the module items` not the `list items`,  so you will get another error.

Either use `from items import items` or change the name of your `items` list.

Your error is most likely from calling `additem(sword)`  above your function `additem`